# How to change the direction of a sprite after a user interacts with the scene?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have an object of SKSpriteNode which has a sequence of actions to be run forever. The actions are simple to move to the most right then back to the most left.

When the user inputs some value in the app, I need to reverse the direction, i. e. if the sprite was moving to the right, I need to make it move to the left and vice versa.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question does not reflect the title

Comment: I want to know the last action that was running just before pausing the sprite animation to be able to reverse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this: (in `swift`)

```
func movament() {

    if isMovingRight == true {
        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.moveByX(10, y: 0, duration: 0.05),
            SKAction.performSelector("movament", onTarget: self),
            ]))
    } else {
        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.moveByX(-10, y: 0, duration: 0.05),
            SKAction.performSelector("movament", onTarget: self),
            ]))
    }
}
```

On user input change `isMovingRight` to oposite value

Was this helpfull?

Comment: I believe that would be adding onto the action list,  which is not what he wants

Comment: @Darvydas: Thanks for reply. Yea it is really helpful. I have done something similar. I have used the data in the 'update' method to determine the animation direction from the x offset, then when the user input is detected, I can reverse the direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
SpriteNode.removeAllactions() // to stop the node
```

Maybe not correct spelling of function